# Combining columns with same name in ArcMap ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.7, basic-license-level

I am currently working on a project using ArcMap 10.7 where I have separated some points into three different layers for different buffer distances. I have used union to combine them again, and dissolved some of the attributes feature classes. However, I am now running into the problem of having three different columns for information that instead of one (some of the columns are null while they are filled in other columns).

Is there a way to combine the three columns into one through ModelBuilder?

Note: these columns are mostly long, lat coordinates, address names, etc.

Unfortunately, my organization only has the Basic license and does not have some of the more convenient / advanced tools available.

Comment: Edit your question and include an image of what you have and what you want. There are many ways to combine data so its not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Why not avoid the problem altogether by keeping your points in a single layer instead of splitting them into separate layers? You can use the Multiple Ring Buffer tool (https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/multiple-ring-buffer.htm) to run multiple buffers at the same time (on all of the points).